# Tweeting status but not image

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to post status and image on twitter.It is twitting status but not twitting image.

My php  code for tweet is

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config-sample.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
  $_SESSION['oauth_status'] = 'oldtoken';
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);


$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

if (200 == $connection->http_code) {

  $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

$image='abc.jpg';

$image1=file_get_contents($image);

$array_disp[0]=$image;
$connection->post('statuses/update',array('status' =>'hello123', 'media[]'=>$image1));

$response=$connection->response['response'];

} else {

  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
```

Now, how to upload image using media post?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `Abraham's` library. It won't work for `upload_with_media`. Here is his statement on this issue

`TwitterOAuth does not currently support media uploads. I hope to add support in the future`

Alternative method is just download `twitteroauth` folder from this [library](https://github.com/robhaswell/twitteroauth) and paste it in your project as `twitteroauth1`. Now, call `require_once('twitteroauth1/twitteroauth.php');`when you are going to tweet with media.

(or)

You can simply copy the `twitteroauth` directory which we have downloaded and replace it in your project. Now, your code should be `require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');` since we replaced the directory. This should WORK!

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth1/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config-sample.php');
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'])     || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$_SESSION['access_token']    ['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']);
$image='abc.jpg';
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$params = array('media[]' => "@{$image}", 'status' => "Testing upload");
$connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', $params,true); 
echo "Picture has uploades successfully";
?>
```